# solve recursion for long execution with callbacks

Tags: java, android, recursion, garbage-collection, stack-overflow

i have created a round based card battle system, that could be executed full automatically

```
private void autoBattle(Battlefield battlefield) {
    // don't stop animation on EnemyCardChoose or EnemyTurn
    if (automatedBattle || 
            battleState == EnumCollection.BattleState.EnemyCardChoose || 
            battleState == EnumCollection.BattleState.EnemyTurn) {
        if (battleState == EnumCollection.BattleState.CardChoose) {
            executeAction(Action.fillHand(), battlefield, true, () -> {
                battleState = EnumCollection.BattleState.PlayerTurn;

                updateCurrentState();

                autoBattle(battlefield);
            });
        } else if (battleState == EnumCollection.BattleState.PlayerTurn) {
            executeAction(Action.turn(), battlefield, true, () -> {
                if (battlefield.isBattleEnd()) {
                    if (battlefield.hasWon(battlefield.getUser())) {
                        battleState = EnumCollection.BattleState.Victory;
                    } else {
                        battleState = EnumCollection.BattleState.Defeat;
                    }
                } else {
                    battleState = EnumCollection.BattleState.EnemyCardChoose;
                }

                updateCurrentState();

                autoBattle(battlefield);
            });
        } else...
    }
}
```

in `executeAction` i:

- check the played cards
- **make animations**
- update the values
- calls the finish callback, that executes `autoBattle` again

The problem is, that repeated execution of `autoBattle` is called from callback, means - the stack is ever grows.

With all the animations the filling of ram comes quick from 170 MB to 300 MB and over.

What is the proper way to execute the loop, with animations that takes a time, and let garbage collector working?

Comment: The simple solution would be to not use recursion at all. Instead have some condition/check in place which determines if `autoBattle` should be called, and than call it within a (`while`) loop.

Comment: `while` dont works with callbacks. I have needed solution with calling after some time,. not emediate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by creation of `Runnable` and `Handler` as global variabled after generation of `battlefield`

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = () ->
    autoBattle(battlefield);
```

and calling `handler.postDelayed(runnable, 30);` instead of `autoBattle(battlefield);`

With that way every 60 MB the RAM was freed and 300 MB was not reached by over 300 loops every cleaning started by 220 MB